# iPhone phone service state

Tags: iphone, telephony

Is there an equivalent API on the iPhone to determine service state like Android? On Android, the service state is available:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html

Ultimately I want to open a "tel:" URL only if the phone is in service from my app. Thanks.